# How to pass a Map to a callback function in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to write a Go program to walk down a directory and find certain file and store that information in a Map.  Here is what I have so far.
I am not sure how to pass the Map to the visit function since it's a callback function.

```
..
type MyFile struct {
    Name       string
    FilePath    string
    FileMD5Hash [16]byte
}

func visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {

    fileName := f.Name()
    if !f.IsDir() && strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(fileName), "myfile") {
        df := parseFile(path)
        fmt.Printf("Visited: %s [%x], %s, %s\n", df.FilePath)
    }

    return nil
}

func parseFile(path string)...

func check(e error) ...

func WalkDir(path string) {
    err := filepath.Walk(path, visit)
    fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", err)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass the Map to the function which returns a `filepath.WalkFunc` and then pass it to `filepath.Walk`. It is a constructor like thing.

```
func visit(map Map) filepath.WalkFunc {
    return func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {

        // do something with map

        fileName := f.Name()
        if !f.IsDir() && strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(fileName), "myfile") {
            df := parseFile(path)
            fmt.Printf("Visited: %s [%x], %s, %s\n", df.FilePath)
        }

        return nil
    }
}

func WalkDir(path string) {
    err := filepath.Walk(path, visit(map))
    fmt.Printf("filepath.Walk() returned %v\n", err)
}
```

Comment: I see you are quite new, you don't have to thank, just accept the answer if you find it useful http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
func (map Map) visit(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
...//Do something with map 
}
var mymap Map

err := filepath.Walk(path, mymap.visit) //mymap.visit express 'func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error' same as visit just with mymap evaluated
```

it's called [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)